# Add jquery animation/transition to menu dropdown

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-animate, transition

I have a fiddle located [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/patricksharer/vhz39t8m/#&togetherjs=UoNvBDvVFS)

The first couple of menu items when clicked have dropdowns. I for life of me cannot figure out how to add an animation/transition for the dropdown that lasts 1 to 2 seconds. I want it to slide down smooth not just click and its there. If anyone could help I would be grateful.

```
<ul id="nav">
<li class="parent"><a class="nav-top" href="#">Web Design <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li><a class="nav-top" href="#">Self Storage Websites</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-top" href="#">Responsive Websites</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="parent"><a class="nav-top" href="#">Internet Marketing <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li><a class="nav-top" href="#">Real SEO</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-top" href="#">PPC (Pay Per Click) Ads</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-top" href="#">Social Media Marketing</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="parent"><a class="nav-top" href="hosting.html">Website Hosting</a></li>
<li class="parent"><a class="nav-top" href="#">About Us <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li><a class="nav-top" href="#">About EiD</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-top" href="#">Careers</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="parent"><a class="nav-top" href="hosting.html">Contact Us</a></li>
```

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.parent').click(function() {
            $(".parent").not(this).find(".sub-nav").removeClass('visible');
            $(this).find('.sub-nav').toggleClass('visible');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added jquery `slideUp` and `slideToggle` functions to give the sliding effect.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent').click(function() {
    $(".parent").not(this).find(".sub-nav").removeClass('visible').slideUp();
    $(this).find('.sub-nav').toggleClass('visible').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

And removed the `display:block`property from class `visible` in css.

Please refer this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/97wbrbfc/1/)